# requestanimationframe drawing with for loop issue

Tags: javascript, for-loop, html5-canvas, requestanimationframe

I'm working on a tetris game - still - and am trying to use requestAnimationFrame to draw my T piece on the black board.

This is the problem.  the requestAnimationFrame draws the piece 2 times, then stops drawing even though the for loop is still running.  That is, after two times, I only see the black background.  When I comment out the black background the piece shows up/animates just fine.

I really am at a loss why this is happening.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const T = [
        [
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
            [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        ],

       [
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
            [0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        ],

       [
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
            [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        ],

        [
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
            [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        ],
    ]

    var piece = T[0];

    const player = {
        position: {x: 5, y: -1},
        piece: piece,
    }

function colorPiece(piece, offset) {
    for(y = 0; y < piece.length; y++) {
        for(x = 0; x < piece.length; x++) {
            if (piece[y][x] !== 0) {
                ctx.fillStyle = "red";
                ctx.fillRect(x + offset.x, y + offset.y, 1, 1);
            }
        }
    }
}

function drawCanvas() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.scale(20, 20);
    colorPiece(player.piece, player.position);
}

function update() {
        drawCanvas();
        requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

update();
```

Comment: Would you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44852846/edit) to show the code that creates `ctx`?  I don't see it in this snippet.  Thanks!  **Also** please explain "stops drawing" vs. "animates" --- I don't see anything in this code that would make the piece move.  Do you mean that after two frames you only get a black rectangle?

Comment: My OCD is bugging me to point out that "piece" is spelled "I-E", not "E-I"... just as long as you don't correct the spelling halfway through your code, you're fine though.

Comment: Patrick, your comment made me laugh.  Sorry.  I think I'm at least consistently spelling it wrong.

Comment: Yes, cxw, I only see the black background after the red t shape iterates through twice.

Comment: Yeah, I'm still learning about clean code.  I tried piece: T[0] and the same issue presents itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - working version, with a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/t4h95qoo/4/).  A number of changes.  The biggest are:

- Don't use `canvas.scale()`, since it's cumulative per [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_scale.asp) (see "More Examples").  Instead, use `20*x` and `20*y` for blocks 20x20.

  **Edit** Based on a [further test](https://jsfiddle.net/t4h95qoo/5/), it looks like this was the most significant change.
- Rename so that `piece` is not used as all of a variable, a field name in `player`, and a parameter of `colorPiece`
- Move the `ctx` creation into `update()` (now called `doUpdate()`) per [this fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/girlie_mac/faRW3/).  Pass `ctx` as a parameter to other functions.
- Move the red `fillStyle` assignment out of the loop, since you only need to do it once, and then you can draw all the rectangles without changing it.
- In the loops:

  ```
  for(var y = 0; y < thePiece.length; ++y) {
      for(var x = 0; x < thePiece[y].length; ++x) { ... } }
  ```

  Keep `x` and `y` [in the local scope](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1470494/2877364), using `var`.

  When you are ready to go across a row, that's `thePiece[y].length`, i.e., the length of the row.  Using `thePiece.length` there would have broken for non-square elements of `T`.
- Added a `<p id="log"/>` and a javascript `framenum` so that I could see that `doUpdate()` was indeed being called.

If you haven't already, make sure to open the console while you're testing so you can see error messages.  If `drawCanvas` causes an error, it will prevent `requestAnimationFrame` from being called again.  I think that's why [the fiddle I linked above](https://jsfiddle.net/girlie_mac/faRW3/) calls `requestAnimationFrame` at the *beginning* rather than the *end* of the frame-draw function.

Hope this helps!

#### Code

```
const T = [
        [
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
            [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        ],

       [
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
            [0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        ],

       [
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
            [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        ],

        [
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
            [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        ],
    ]

    const player = {
        position: {x: 5, y: -1},
        piece: T[0]
    }

function colorPiece(ctx, thePiece, offset) {
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    for(var y = 0; y < thePiece.length; ++y) {
        for(var x = 0; x < thePiece[y].length; ++x) {
            if (thePiece[y][x] !== 0) {
                ctx.fillRect(20*(x + offset.x), 20*(y + offset.y), 20, 20);
            }
        }
    }
}

function drawCanvas(ctx) {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    colorPiece(ctx, player.piece, player.position);
}

var framenum=0;

function doUpdate(timestamp) {
        document.getElementById("log").innerHTML = framenum.toString();
        ++framenum;
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        drawCanvas(ctx);
        window.requestAnimationFrame(doUpdate);
}

doUpdate();
```

Comment: Yes!  It did not even occur to me the fillStyle needed to proceed the fillRect.  I tweaked my code bit by bit according to your suggestions with debugger, and as soon as I put the fillStyle before the fillRect, the problem was fixed.  Thank you so much for the help!!!